# How to render a formatted template string in React instead of one paragraph?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, string-literals, template-literals

I am setting my state as follows -

```
setMessage(color, text) {
        this.setState({ message: { color: color, text: text } });
    }

body = `These are your options to raise money:​
Increase your credit allowance (invite new people into the game, this increases your overdraft auto`

this.setMessage('red', `${body}` );
```

I am rendering it is {this.state.message.text}, however it doesn't render the multiple lines, instead it all gets squeezed into  **one paragraph**.

How do I fix it and render it?

Comment: HTML will collapse whitespace by default. You can preserve whitespace using css `white-space: pre`

Comment: But i'm rendering it using {this.state.message.text}, how exactly do I set this style for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jsx to do that. I have also faced this issue, I solved it like this and it did work for me.
You can use either React fragment tag or any valid jsx tag

```
setMessage(color, text) {
        this.setState({ message: { color: color, text: text } });
    }

body = <>These are your options to raise money:​<br />
Increase your credit allowance (invite new people into the game, this increases your overdraft auto</>

this.setMessage('red', body );
```